# Why is Twitto not secure?

Tags: php, web-framework

I've come across [Twitto](http://twitto.org/), which basically is a web framework that fits in a tweet. It is so short that I can post the code here :

```
require __DIR__.'/c.php';
if (!is_callable($c = @$_GET['c'] ?: function() { echo 'Woah!'; }))
  throw new Exception('Error');
$c();
```

It basically searches for a file named c.php and calls whatever function in that files that is the same name as `$_GET['c']`.

On the project's website, there is a big red banner at the bottom of the page that reads :

> » TWITTO IS NOT SECURE, DON'T USE IT FOR YOUR NEXT WEBSITE «

I am no PHP guru, but to me it looks like if you take all the precautions you normally take with a standard PHP site (sanitizing user input, etc), it should be secure enough ?

What is wrong with this tiny framework ?

EDIT : I understand why this framework is not secure AS-IS, but with the proper bootstrapping and validation checks and everything inside the function you call, it should be just as secure as any other framework ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not secure, since it allows to run any function available on your system.

It's difficult to find a good example of a function which will cause too much harm, since, for example, PHP doesn't have a magic "format my server" parameterless function. Still:

> twitto.php?c=phpinfo

for example will display everything about your system to a hacker. Pretty nice, isn't it?

In the same way, you may add some parameterless functions to your app, without expecting them to be called by the end users. For example:

- `DisplayUsersInfo()` flushes the information about the users, including the sensitive data,
- `ShowAdminTab(TAB_USERS)` shows the users tab in the administration panel by calling `DisplayUsersInfo`.

The `ShowAdminTab($tab)` is called only after authentication and other means which protect the administration panel from unauthorized access. Fine. Then somebody calls `twitto.php?c=DisplayUsersInfo`. No authentication required.

Answer (score 1):

I'ts because of this:

> The "Hello World!" controller is now accessible at
>   /twitto.php?c=hello_world.

Anybody can execute your PHP SERVER SIDE code from any browser! (With a simple HTTP GET)!

---

**EDIT** I'm pretty sure this call **any standard PHP** function, Not just the ones in the `C.php` file, how can you secure that?

Comment: The function is called without any parameters... I can't think of anything harmful that could be done with a standard PHP function that takes no parameters

Comment: @CollinHockey Look at  the Code, where is checking if the function called exists in the c.php file? Its just executing whatever is passed in.

Comment: @Morons: It is executing whatever is passed id but without any parameters. Give me a standard PHP function that can break something which does not require any argument.

Comment: What about this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-child-terminate.php

Comment: @Morons I didn't even think of that before. I wasn't thinking about built-ins, but only about the explicitly included files.